# vortex moduli compactness and projectivity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Are  $U(1)$ vortex moduli spaces on compact Kaehler surfaces (four manifolds)
compact? If the base manifold is projective, will the moduli space be projective?

Previous search: on Kaehler surfaces, the perturbed Seiberg-Witten moduli space, under certain conditions, is the vortex moduli space, so compactness holds for these moduli spaces.
But in case of vortices, not all line bundles generate spin${}_c$ structures. What will happen in these cases?

Comment: Crossposted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2732026.